# How to permanently fix fsck check failing during boot

Tags: boot, filesystem, asus

My laptop is an [ASUS FX505DY](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DY/specifications/). I bought it without any OS and installed Ubuntu 19.10, then upgraded to 20.04 a few months later (no dual-boot).

From time to time, the system doesn't boot normally and goes into "emergency mode" (it's actually the 3rd time after about 1 year of use). Each time the cause is `fsck` failing to check `/home` partition. `journalctl` gives me:

```
oct. 30 12:19:44 poulpito systemd-fsck[624]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
oct. 30 12:19:44 poulpito systemd[1]: Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/91e9d404-4089-4b8d-af58-5aebcd76b5a0.
```

I can easily fix it with: `fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda4`. I hit enter to every questions and then I can reboot and enjoy an OS running normally. But I feel uneasy with the problem recurring and I would like to fix it permanently.

So my questions are:

1. Why file system get corrupted on this partition? Could it be a hardware problem? Do I need to change some parameters or configuration or switch to ext3? I've run `smartctl -t short /dev/sda4` in recovery mode and no error were reported.
2. `/home` is on a sata HDD where I also have `/var`, `/tmp` and `swap` partitions. I never get any `fsck` check problem for these. Perhaps because the boot sequence just doesn't check these partitions? Or corruptions really happen just on `/home`?
3. The last time I had to run `fsck.ext4`, I got these questions:

- pass 1: `inode <inode id> seems to contain garbage` and `inode <inode id> passes checks, but checksum does not match inode`, actually 16 messages of these kinds with contiguous inode numbers
- pass 2: `entry '<filename>' in <path> (<inode id>) has deleted/unused inode <inode id>` (inode numbers suggest that it is a mere consequence of inodes cleared during pass 1
- pass 4: `inode <inode id> ref count is <count>, should be <count>` (again, seems to be just a consequence of pass 2)
- pass 5: inode and block bitmap differences, free inodes/free blocks/directories count wrong

  Does this mean that I lose some data? Since all impacted inodes are related to application files in `$HOME/.config/` or `$HOME/.local/`, I don't see directly the effect of a missing or corrupted file...

4. How do I prevent the file system to be corrupted?

Thanks!

Gilles

**EDIT 1**: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBeEE.png) of SMART data window in Disks app.

`smartctl` gives roughly the same data in english:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1350
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       670
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       2224
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   113   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       509
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       24418
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 19/42)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       1931
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       263
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2218         -
```

**EDIT 2**: and another [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2jL.png) for gparted.

**EDIT 3**: As suggested, I've upgraded my BIOS firmware. Well, the upgrade went fine and didn't break anything. For sure, it's better to have firmware up-to-date in any case. But I must confess that I don't understand how the BIOS could be responsible of FS corruptions on a single partition of my HDD and I can't see any way to verify that the problem is really solved. I give up for now and I'll update this post if the problem happen again. UPDATE: the same error occurred again about two months after original post and BIOS update.

**EDIT 4**: More details, as requested by @heynnema

```
$ free -h
              total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,3Gi       3,8Gi        49Mi       1,5Gi       5,0Gi
Partition d'échange:        15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

`sudo lshw -C memory` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sq9qy9kxVb/

`zgrep -i gnome-software /var/log/syslog*` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qqy99YnFvC/

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=cbee80f8-6637-44e3-8dbd-7f710be58e54 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=E06D-1632  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=91e9d404-4089-4b8d-af58-5aebcd76b5a0 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /tmp was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=51e800d3-f199-490a-bb7a-d2f49635e71c /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=da892f2f-b8d2-47f5-a5e7-30e779fe9d2c /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7317598f-60e6-475e-a7d0-38503bac42fc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data** window for the drive. This data window is scrollable, so it might take 2 screenshots to get it all. Also show me a `gparted` screenshot.

Comment: @heynnema: screenshot added

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is it possible to get the SMART Data screenshot in English?

Comment: @heynnema: I don't know how to switch GUI to english but I added `smartctl` output. I think it's the same data.

Comment: Your disk looks good. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` returned `FX505DY.313`

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Thanks for doing the BIOS update. Unfortunately ASUS chose to not give ANY documentation about what the various BIOSs rectify, so it's real difficult to know if it will ultimately fix the FS corruption problem. It appears that your disk is fine, according to SMART, so we'll just have to wait and see. Please do keep me posted. Last thought... show me `cat /etc/fstab` and I'll take a quick look.

Comment: Note that on https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1042991, the first step in solving both examples, says to update the BIOS :-)

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DY [Specs](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DY/specifications/)

You have BIOS version 313.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 315, dated 3/27/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DY/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model computer.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Update #1:**

Edit your question and show me:

`free -h`

`sudo lshw -C memory`

`grep -i gnome-software /var/log/syslog*` (post to paste.ubuntu.com)

`cat /etc/fstab`

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #2:**

Although I normally wouldn't recommend this, I think it's time to reinstall Ubuntu, clean install, if possible. Backup your data. Use `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive). Don't manually build separate /tmp and /var and swap partitions. Use a 4G /swapfile instead of a swap partition (if you're not hibernating). Then restore your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, the BIOS update didn't fix the problem. After 2 months, it pops up again:


`janv. 23 18:26:39 poulpito systemd-fsck[640]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
janv. 23 18:26:39 poulpito systemd[1]: Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/91e9d404-4089-4b8d-af58-5aebcd76b5a0.`

Comment: @GillesBassière Does /var/log/syslog* have anything to say about sdxx?

Comment: @GillesBassière Does `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` give any results?

Comment: no, it doesn't give any results

Comment: @GillesBassière Let's see `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. If it's lengthy, please post it to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help @heynnema! Here is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yC7py4pWZC/
I sent only those for Jan 23, the day of the error. Let me know if you want to see other days.
Interestingly, this day I boot my laptop in the morning with no apparent problem (see log around 09:11:34), then shut it down and boot it again in the evening (it failed around 18:29, I "fixed" it with `fsck -y`, then boot again around 19:07 as shown in the logs). The log shows 2 lines with "EXT4-fs error" around 10:02:50.
Here is the full log for the minute 10:02 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H8yD8TwgqK/

Comment: @GillesBassière Please see Update #1 in my answer. How old is the 1TB drive /dev/sda?

Comment: OK, I added these commands' output to my question, see edit n°4.
The laptop is about 1 year old and the HDD is the original one.
Regarding memtest, I'll do that overnight and let you know.

Comment: @GillesBassière In syslog I see lots of these gnome-software errors... "message repeated 80 times: [ xb_builder_node_unlink: assertion 'XB_IS_BUILDER_NODE (self)' failed]". Let me know how memtest goes.

Comment: I did memtest last night, 13 tests and 4 passes but 0 errors.
Regarding xb_builder_node_unlink error, I also noticed it occurred right after the EXT4fs-error. But it also occurred many times (almost every day) without being related to EXT4-fs error.

Comment: @GillesBassière Good news on memtest. Everything seems to be checking out. And although I normally wouldn't recommend this, I think it's time to reinstall Ubuntu, clean install, if possible. Backup your data. Use `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive). Don't manually build separate /tmp and /var and swap partitions. Use a 4G /swapfile instead of a swap partition. Then restore your data. See Update #2.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help and advice. I'll try reinstalling, someday.
Naive question: is ext4 a good choice for file system? I mean is it still considered rather new or is it robust and mature?
And is it possible that my HDD somehow has a problem (at firmware or hardware level)?

Comment: @GillesBassière ext4 is mature, and the correct/default choice. The SMART data for the HDD looks fine. I'd reinstall sooner than later. Do you dual boot with Windows?

Comment: No dual boot, Ubuntu is the only OS installed on this computer.